# Shell status codes in make

Tags: shell, makefile

I use a Makefile (with GNU make running under Linux) to automate my grunt work when refactoring a Python script.
The script creates an output file, and I want to make sure that the output file remains unchanged in face of my refactorings.

However, I found no way to get the status code of a command to affect a subsequent shell if command.

The following rule illustrates the problem:

```
check-cond-codes:
    diff report2008_4.csv report2008_4.csv-save-for-regression-testing; echo no differences: =$$!=
    diff -q poalim report2008_4.csv; echo differences: =$$!=
```

The first 'diff' compares two equal files, and the second one compares two different files.
The output is:

```
diff report2008_4.csv report2008_4.csv-save-for-regression-testing; echo no differences: =$!=
no differences: ==
diff -q poalim report2008_4.csv; echo differences: =$!=
Files poalim and report2008_4.csv differ
differences: ==
```

So obviously '$$!' is the wrong variable to capture the status code of 'diff'.
Even using
    SHELL := /bin/bash
at beginning of the Makefile did not solve the problem.

A variable returning the value, which I need, would (if it exists at all) be used in an 'if' command in the real rule.

The alternative of creating a small ad-hoc shell script in lieu of writing all commands inline in the Makefile is undesirable, but I'll use it as a last resort.

Related:

- [How to make a failing shell command interrupt make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225542/how-to-make-a-failing-shell-command-interrupt-make)

Comment: I think you are looking for the `.SHELLSTATUS` variable: [How to get exit status of a shell command used in GNU Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315089/how-to-get-exit-status-of-a-shell-command-used-in-gnu-makefile/16315249)

Answer (score 38):

I think you're looking for the `$?` shell variable, which gives the exit code of the previous command.  For example:

```
$ diff foo.txt foo.txt
$ echo $?
0
```

To use this in your makefile, you would have to escape the `$`, as in `$$?`:

```
all:
    diff foo.txt foo.txt ; if [ $$? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "no differences" ; fi
```

Do note that each command in your rule body in make is run in a separate subshell.  For example, the following will not work:

```
all:
    diff foo.txt foo.txt
    if [ $$? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "no differences" ; fi
```

Because the `diff` and the `if` commands are executed in different shell processes.  If you want to use the output status from the command, you must do so in the context of the same shell, as in my previous example.

Comment: The motivation of $$ is useful.

Comment: Plain `diff foo.txt foo.txt && echo "no differences"` looks slimmer :)

Comment: CAUTION: I observed that `echo $$? ;` causes $$? to become 0 after the echo, probably because echo was a success.  This caused my if statement to always be true, to confirm i tested `echo $$?; echo $$?;` in case of errorlevel=1 it does echo 1 then 0

Comment: @SketchBookGames naturally that's so, because the exit status of `echo` is zero.

Answer (score 4):

Use '$$?' instead of '$$!' (thanks to 4th answer of [Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code))

Comment: I cannot find anything about `$$!` in the link you provided.  

 Can you please be more specific by modifying the URL and give the one directly pointing `to 4th answer of Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code` by using the `share` link below the 4th answer if it is still at the 4th position

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that each of your commands is being run in separate subshells.

That's why you quite often see something like:

```
my_target:
    do something \
    do something else \
    do last thing.
```

And when debugging, don't forget the every helpful -n option which will print the commands but not execute them and the -p option which will show you the complete make environment including where the various bits and pieces have been set.

HTH

cheers,

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? Original poster @Omer Zak is active as of 2 days ago. While it doesn't provide a copy-paste answer, it does accurately present the technique needed to solve the problem (multi-line Bash).

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing the result code to an `if`, you could simply do:

```
all:
    if diff foo.txt foo.txt ; then echo "no differences" ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The bash variable is `$?`, but why do you want to print out the status code anyway?

Answer (score -4):

Try `\$?' I think the $$ is being interpreted by the makefile