# How to get exit status of a shell command used in GNU Makefile?

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile rule in while I am executing a linux tool. I need to check the exit status of the tool command, and if that command fails the make has to be aborted.

I tried checking with $?, $$? \$? etc in the makefile. But they gives me syntax error when makefile runs.

What is the right way to do this ?

Here is the relevant rule in Makefile

> ```
>     mycommand \
>     if [ $$? -ne 0 ]; \
>     then \
>         echo "mycommand failed"; \
>         false; \
>     fi
> ```

Comment: Have you tried `echo $?`? This can help --> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-how-to-determine-the-exit-status-of-linux-and-unix-command/

Comment: Eh? Make automatically checks the exit status of the tool, and aborts on error. A simple `mycommand` suffices, no?

Comment: The syntax error comes from make removing the line breaks before passing the text block to the shell. Simply add `;`s to the end of each line (apart from the `then` and `fi`) and your snippet will lose its syntax errors.

Comment: @bobbogo, thanks it worked. The syntax error was due to missing ;

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In the makefile-:

```
mycommand || (echo "mycommand failed $$?"; exit 1)
```

Each line in the makefile action invokes a new shell - the error must be checked in the action line where the command failed.

If mycommand fails the logic branches to the echo statement then exits.

Comment: In my case `echo` prints the message, but `exit 1` does not abort my Makefile execution.  :(

Comment: Replacing `exit 1` with `sh -c 'exit 1'` solved my problem.

Answer (score 31):

Here are a couple of other approaches:

---

#### [`shell` & `.SHELLSTATUS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)

```
some_recipe:
    @echo $(shell echo 'doing stuff'; exit 123)
    @echo 'command exited with $(.SHELLSTATUS)'
    @exit $(.SHELLSTATUS)
```

Output:

```
$ make some_recipe

doing stuff
command exited with 123      
make: *** [Makefile:4: some_recipe] Error 123
```

It does have the caveat that the `shell` command output isn't streamed, so you just end up with a dump to stdout when it finishes.

---

#### [`$?`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#EXSREF)

```
some_recipe:
    @echo 'doing stuff'; sh -c 'exit 123';\
    EXIT_CODE=$$?;\
    echo "command exited with $$EXIT_CODE";\
    exit $$EXIT_CODE
```

Or, a bit easier to read:

```
.ONESHELL:

some_recipe:
    @echo 'doing stuff'; sh -c 'exit 123'
    @EXIT_CODE=$$?
    @echo "command exited with $$EXIT_CODE"
    @exit $$EXIT_CODE
```

Output:

```
$ make some_recipe

doing stuff                  
command exited with 123      
make: *** [Makefile:2: some_recipe] Error 123
```

It's essentially one string of commands, executed in the same shell.

Comment: The `$(shell ...)` in the first recipe might be confusing but it does only evaluate if that recipe is executed (I originally thought otherwise, whoops)

Comment: `.SHELLSTATUS` must have appeared recently, probably, in GNU Make >= 4.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is for the `make` to be aborted iff the tool exits with a nonzero status, `make` will already do that by default.

Example `Makefile`:

```
a: b
    @echo making $@
b:
    @echo making $@
    @false
    @echo already failed
```

.
This is what happens with my `make`:

```
$ make
making b
make: *** [Makefile:6: b] Error 1
```

Make sure partially or wholly created targets are removed in case you fail.
For instance, this

```
a: b
    @gena $+ > $@
b:
    @genb > $@
```

is incorrect: if on the first try, `genb` fails, it will probably leave an incorrect `b`, which, on the second try, `make` will assume is correct.  So you need to do something like

```
a: b
    @gena $+ > $@ || { rm $@; exit 1; }
b:
    @genb > $@
```

Answer (score 1):

To those who can't still fix it, the original snippet in the question missed a semicolon after `mycommand`. So, the working example is:

```
    mycommand; \  # <<== here's the missing semicolon
    if [ $$? -ne 0 ]; \
    then \
        echo "mycommand failed"; \
        false; \
    fi
```

Comment: Probably refactor to avoid this, though. See also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)