# Gnu make: Run shell command and use exit code to set global variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a complicated script `c.sh` that tests some part of the environment of the machine make is running. It should be run using `bash`. It prints some useful information for the use to `stdout` and `stderr`. If some special condition is met, `c.sh` exists with exit code 1, otherwise 0. Other exit codes might occur if something goes wrong. Depending on the exit code, I want to execute different recipes.

```
all:
    # test using c.sh

everything-OK: # prerequisites
    # *recurse* on this if c.sh exits with zero
    # e.g. "$(MAKE) everything-OK" in all if ...

something-went-wrong: # prerequisites
    # *recurse* on this if c.sh exists with anything else
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324918) useful answer but it does not quite help. Since I cannot seem to get the recursion working or the if switch depending on the exit code. Using `$(.SHELLSTATUS)` looked promising at first, but that solution does not redirect `stdout` from the script immediately.

An alternative solution might look like this:

```
EVERYTHING_OK = 0 # 0: false, 1: true

all:
    # test using c.sh
    # set EVERYTHING_OK depending on exit code
    $(MAKE) second-stage

ifeq (1,EVERYTHING_OK)
second-stage: # prerequisites
    # ...
else
second-stage: # prerequisites
    # ...
endif
```

(I prefer this, since I can put the if condition in a macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested only in the exit status of your script the easiest is probably to capture it in a make variable and use it in make conditionals or target names. Example with target names:

```
C_EXIT_STATUS := $(shell ./c.sh &> /dev/null; echo $$?)

.PHONY: all everithing-%

all: everything-$(C_EXIT_STATUS)

everything-0:
    @echo "all right"

everything-%:
    @echo "not all right ($*)"
```

And then, if `./c.sh` exits with status 0:

```
$ make all
all right
```

While if it exits with status 7:

```
$ make all
not all right (7)
```

Example with make conditionals:

```
C_EXIT_STATUS := $(shell ./c.sh &> /dev/null; echo $$?)

.PHONY: all

ifeq ($(C_EXIT_STATUS),0)
all:
    @echo "all right"
else
all:
    @echo "not all right ($(C_EXIT_STATUS))"
endif
```

And last but not least, as you suggested yourself, recursive make is also an option:

```
.PHONY: all

ifeq ($(C_EXIT_STATUS),)
all:
    s=0; ./c.sh &> /dev/null || s=$$?; \
    $(MAKE) C_EXIT_STATUS=$$s
else ifeq ($(C_EXIT_STATUS),0)
all:
    @echo "all right"
else
all:
    @echo "not all right ($(C_EXIT_STATUS))"
endif
```

Comment: Can I also use `1>&2` instead of `&>` to redirect the output of the call to `c.sh`?

Comment: Are you trying to capture the standard output **and** the exit status in make variables?

Comment: I want the stdout (and -err) to remain visible, because it contains error information. I tested this already and it works as intended.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. Yes, absolutely, you can redirect `stdout` to `stderr` and keep `stdout` for the exit status.