# What does "$$?" mean in this makefile snippet?

Tags: bash, makefile

What does "$$?" mean in below Makefile snippet?

```
$(PROGS): FORCE
    @cd $(BUILD_DIRECTORY_PATH)/$@; \
    mkdir -p obj; \
    $(MAKE) || exit "$$?"; \  <====== HERE
```

### ADD 1

I guess it means `exit "$?"` in bash since `$$` in makefile escapes to `$`.

But what does  `exit "$?"` mean then?

Comment: Exit with the return code of the previous command. Try searching on symbolhound if you have trouble googling code. i.e http://symbolhound.com/?q=exit+%24%3F+bash

Comment: @123  Many thanks! *Symbolhound* is simply awesome for coders! I found the answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$? is the return code when a program exits or finishes. Therefore, in your line

```
$(MAKE) || exit "$$?"
```

It will execute `$(MAKE)`. If this program does not finish correctly, it will have a return code different from 0 and then the `exit "$$?"` will be executed. which will make the current process to exit to shell with the same return code as the `$(MAKE)` program, which you will be able to show executing `echo $?` in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Said another way, `$$?` is the Makefile equivalent of `$?`.  In Make, to escape `$?` you need to use `$$?`.  More info: [Shell status codes in make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748445/shell-status-codes-in-make)

---

Not that you've asked, but I generally tell folks to avoid Make.  If you have a choice:

1. Install pipx . Project URL: https://pypa.github.io/pipx/ .
2. Use pipx to install invoke (`pipx install invoke`). Project URL: https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke
3. Use Python instead of strange Make syntax.