# Makefile: How to assign a command's output and exit code to a variable?

Tags: makefile

I am searching for a way to get the output and the exit code of a command to variables in a makefile.

Basicly I want this: (bash)

```bsh
output=$(whoami)
returnval=$?
echo "OUT:"
echo $output
echo "RET:"
echo $returnval
```

to be in a makefile

note: should work in a rule section

Thanks

EDIT: SOLVED

```
$(eval OUTPUT_RC="$(shell whoami;echo $$?)")
$(eval OUTPUT="$(shell echo $(OUTPUT_RC) | sed -e "s/^\(.*\)\(.\{2\}\)$$/\1/")")
$(eval RC="$(shell echo $(OUTPUT_RC) | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$$/\1/")")
echo $(OUTPUT)
echo $(RC)
```

Comment: Another solution that is also complicated but uses less external processes can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40710111/1905491 You don't need the `eval`s there btw. Assinging with `:=` should suffice.

Comment: Using a shell to split the combined result is a lot more awful than just running two separate commands. Why would you ever expect `whoami` to return an error?

Comment: `whoami` is just an example imagine a compiler command, you do not want to run a compiler command two times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `eval` anyway, make it print things you can `eval` directly.

```
$(eval $(shell echo OUTPUT_RC=`whoami`; echo $$?))
OUTPUT=$(word 1,$(OUTPUT_RC))
RC=$(word 2,$(OUTPUT_RC))
```

Answer (score -1):

GNU make offers the `shell` function, as in:

```
OUTPUT=$(shell whoami)
OUTPUT_RC=$(shell whoami; echo $$?)
```

Comment: the bad thing about this is that it runs 2 times, imagin it is an compile command