# Make: Capture output of shell command and return code at same time

Tags: shell, makefile, return-value

In make, if I want to capture the output of a shell command, I do something like this

```
RESULT:=$(shell $(COMMAND))
```

If I want to check if a command executed properly, I do this

```
RETURN_CODE := $(shell $(COMMAND); echo $$?)
```

How can I do both simultaneously, i.e. execute the command once, store the output, but also check the return code?

**EDIT**
Duplicate here although his solution is not pleasant:
[Makefile: Output and Exitcode to variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157083/makefile-output-and-exitcode-to-variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
OUTPUT_WITH_RC := $(shell $(COMMAND); echo $$?)
RETURN_CODE := $(lastword $(OUTPUT_WITH_RC))
OUTPUT := $(subst $(RETURN_CODE)QQQQ,,$(OUTPUT_WITH_RC)QQQQ)
```

If your command fails, it will probably write to stderr; you can use this to capture everything:

```
OUTPUT_WITH_RC := $(shell $(COMMAND) 2>$1; echo $$?)
```

Comment: Didn't know about lastword, that's certainly nicer than the sed used in the linked answer. Is there a nice way to then get the output without the return code?

Comment: see update; use something that cannot appear in output instead of `QQQ`