# Which xarch for SHA extensions on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, sha, intrinsics, solaris-studio

Oracle released Sun Studio 12.6 recently. We have a SHA-1 and SHA-256 [intrinsic based implementation](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/sha-simd.cpp) (for ARM and Intel), and we want to enable the extension on Solaris i86 machines.

The 12.6 manual and `-xarch` options is available at [A.2.115.3 -xarch Flags for x86](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77789/bkana.html#indexterm-id-725), but it does not discuss SHA.

Which `-xarch` option do we use for SHA?

Comment: How do "arch" (as in target architecture?) and "SHA" (as in an overgeneralization of a hash family?) relate?

Comment: @user2864740 - Xarch is used to select and instruction set architecture. SunCC's `-xarch=XXX` is similar to GCC's `-mXXX`. Under GCC we can use `-msha` to enable the ISA and gain access to the SHA instructions. I'm looking for the same for Sun Studio and SunCC.

Comment: @user2864740 in this case "SHA" is a reference to the Intel instruction set extensions for calculating hashes via the SHA-1 and SHA-256 algorithms: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sha-extensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Studio 12.6 doesn't support the SHA instruction set (and I strongly suspect it doesn't since I can't find "SHA" mentioned at all, in any form, in the [What's New in the Oracle Developer Studio 12.6 Release](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77784/index.html) documentation), you're out of luck.

Almost.

What you can do is create your own inline assembler functions.  [See `man inline`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E54439/inline-4.html):

> **inline(4)**
>
> **Name**
>
> inline, filename.il - Assembly language inline template files
>
> **Description**
>
> Assembly language call instructions are replaced by a copy of their
>   corresponding function body obtained from the inline template (*.il)
>   file.
>
> Inline template files have a suffix of .il, for example:
>
> ```
> % CC foo.il hello.c
> ```
>
> Inlining is done by the compiler's code generator.
>
> ...
>
> **Examples**
>
> Please review libm.il or vis.il for examples. You can find a version of these libraries that is specific to each supported architecture under the compiler's lib/ directory.
>
> ...

An example [can be found here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/inline-assembly-138602.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Performance Tuning With Sun Studio Compilers and Inline Assembly Code**
>
> ...
>
> This paper provides a demonstration of how to measure the performance
>   of a critical piece of code. An example using a compiler flag and
>   **another example using inline assembly code** are provided. The results are compared to show the benefits and differences of each
>   approach.
>
> ...
>
> **Example 8: Inline Assembly Code for the Iterative Mandelbrot Calculation**
>
> Knowing all these facts, the inline code can be written, as shown in
>   Example 8.
>
> ```
> .inline mandel_il,0
> // x is stored in %xmm0
> // y is stored in %xmm1
> // 4.0 is stored in %xmm2
> // max_int is stored in %rdi
>
> // set registers to zero
>   xorps %xmm3, %xmm3
>   xorps %xmm4, %xmm4
>   xorps %xmm5, %xmm5
>   xorps %xmm6, %xmm6
>   xorps %xmm7, %xmm7
>   xorq %rax, %rax
>
> .loop:
> // check to see if u2 - v2 > 4.0
>   movss %xmm5, %xmm7
>   addss %xmm6, %xmm7
>   ucomiss %xmm2, %xmm7
>   jp     .exit
>   jae    .exit
>
> // v = 2 * v * u + y
>   mulss %xmm3, %xmm4
>   addss %xmm4, %xmm4
>   addss %xmm1, %xmm4
> // u = u2 - v2 + x
>   movss %xmm5, %xmm3
>   subss %xmm6, %xmm3
>   addss %xmm0, %xmm3
> // u2 = u * u
>   movss %xmm3, %xmm5
>   mulss %xmm3, %xmm5
> // v2 = v * v
>   movss %xmm4, %xmm6
>   mulss %xmm4, %xmm6
>
>   incl %eax
>   cmpl %edi, %eax
>   jl .loop
>
> .exit:
> // end of mandel_il
> .end
> ```

It's not hard at all. I had to write a lot of SPARC inline assembler functions for a customer I was consulting for back in the Solaris 8 days, some of them were pretty basic - effectively one-liners to wrap a single instruction.  I swear some of them wound up in later versions of the Studio compiler suite (since we were sub-contracted by Sun itself, that's not surprising, nevermind the fact that some of them were blatantly obvious - `floor()` and `ceil()`, IIRC, were two of them - and should have been there in the first place...)