# How to make GNU Make fail if a shell command assigned to a variable failed?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Make variable:

```
PASSWORD:=$(shell vault read -field=password test/password)
```

If `vault` is not installed, `make` will print `make: vault: Command not found`, but continue executing the recipe. How do I make it fail and stop execution if the expression fails?

Comment: Is it a viable solution to test for the presence of `vault` e.g. with `which vault` outside the recipe?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/225542/5989200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are intending to use a [`call` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function), and want to abort at one central place (so that future users of `GET_SECRET` do not forget to check e.g. `.SHELLSTATUS`), I found this hack practical:

```
GET_SECRET = $(shell vault read -field=$(1) $(2) || { echo >&2 "Error reading field $(1) from vault path $(2), aborting"; kill $$PPID; })
```

The parent `make` process is killed of `shell` error. See also [225542/how-to-make-a-failing-shell-command-interrupt-make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225542/how-to-make-a-failing-shell-command-interrupt-make) and [50958731/assign-shell-output-to-variable-or-exit-terminate-makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958731/assign-shell-output-to-variable-or-exit-terminate-makefile)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach:

```
$ cat err.mk
PASSWORD:=$(shell vault read -field=password test/password)
ifndef PASSWORD
$(error PASSWORD not set (maybe vault failed?))
endif
$ make -f err.mk
make: vault: Command not found
err.mk:3: *** PASSWORD not set (maybe vault failed?).  Stop.
```

Comment: If you have a new-enough GNU make you could use this instead of `ifndef`: `$(or $(PASSWORD), $(error PASSWORD not set))` which is slightly nicer to read (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this idea should work:

```
X!=lsx /

all:
ifeq (${.SHELLSTATUS},0)
    @echo OK
else
    @exit 1
endif
```

For example you can create a `check:` PHONY-target which is needed by every (other) target.

Explanation see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function):

> After the shell function or ‘!=’ assignment operator is used, its exit
>   status is placed in the .SHELLSTATUS variable.

The `X=$(shell ls /)` doesn't work but IMHO should.