# Assign shell output to variable or exit ( terminate makefile )

Tags: bash, makefile

How can I terminate Makefile with an error if shell command output an $$? -ne 0 ?

```
HELPER := $(shell dirname $(abspath $(lastword 
VERSION ?= $(shell . $(HELPER); getVersion) ||  (echo "getVersion failed '$$?' status"; exit 1)

test:
        @echo "What is going on?$(VERSION) ?"
```

**helper.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
printError() {
    echo "[MAKE] $1" 2>/dev/stderr
}
getVersion() {
    version=$(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h') 2>/dev/null)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        printError "Getting git tag for version failed. Checkout existing tag or"
        printError "provide your own version 'make <action> VERSION=<your-version>'"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "${version}"
    exit 0
}
```

**output:**

```
$ make test
What is going on?[MAKE] Getting git tag for version failed. Checkout existing tag or [MAKE] provide your own version 'make <action> VERSION=<your-version>' ||  (echo getVersion failed $? status; exit 1) ?
```

I cannot terminate it on error ( getVersion returns 1 ) but also error messages that are piped to `/dev/stderr` are getting to `VERSION` variable

Comment: Makefile questions should be tagged make, not shell. Make syntax is not shell syntax -- it's used to *generate* shell commands, but it is itself its own very different thing.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59392005/491884, you can use a hack (kill parent make process with `|| kill $$PPID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, answers to extra questions.  This line is clearly wrong; I assume you just had a cut/paste error:

```
HELPER := $(shell dirname $(abspath $(lastword
```

I don't know why you're breaking out to the shell here and running its `dirname` but whatever.

Second, this from your helper script:

```
echo "[MAKE] $1" 2>/dev/stderr
```

does not do at all what you want: it says "take the output going to file descriptor 2 (stderr) and pipe it to `/dev/stderr`.  Since `echo` doesn't print anything to stderr this is basically a no-op.  You appear to want to redirect stdout (file descriptor 1) to stderr; that would be this:

```
echo "[MAKE] $1" >/dev/stderr
```

although the more correct and portable way to write this is:

```
echo "[MAKE] $1" 1>&2
```

which sets fd1 to write to wherever fd2 is writing.

Now on to your real question: `make` has no concept of shell operators like `||` or `&&`, so here:

```
VERSION ?= $(shell . $(HELPER); getVersion) ||  (echo "getVersion failed '$$?' status"; exit 1)
```

the `||` etc. is simply treated as text; it sets `VERSION` to the string:

```
 <whatever `shell`prints> ||  (echo "getVersion failed '$$?' status"; exit 1)
```

which is exactly what you see.

If you have a new-enough version of GNU make (4.2 or above) you can use the `.SHELLSTATUS` variable to find out the exit status of the last shell.  Then you could do something like this:

```
.SHELLSTATUS = 0
VERSION ?= $(shell . $(HELPER); getVersion)
$(if $(filter-out 0,$(.SHELLSTATUS)),$(error getVersion failed '$(.SHELLSTATUS)' status))
```

(you have to set it first because you're using `?=` here so sometimes no shell function will be invoked).

If you need to be portable to earlier versions of GNU make, or if you just prefer to use something a bit more clear, you can check the value of `VARIABLE`.  If you change your script so it writes errors to stderr and writes nothing to stdout on failure you can use:

```
VERSION ?= $(shell . $(HELPER); getVersion)
$(if $(VERSION),,$(error getVersion failed))
```

Comment: I've redirected my printError to 1>&2 but now VERSION variable contains error message. Every time I use $(VERSION) which I suppose to be empty I get error message printed out to my terminal.

Comment: You must have done something else wrong or different.  I ran this: `echo 'VER := $(shell echo hi 1>&2) | make -f-` and this printed `hi` which it would not have done if the output was captured in the `VER` variable.